# Cookies aren't available on new window on localhost

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm using the following code to set a cookie

```
function setCookie(key, value) {
  var expires = new Date();
  expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  document.cookie = key + '=' + value + ';expires=' + expires.toUTCString();
}
setCookie('test', '1');
```

The code is setting the cookie correctly (inspect element reveals the cookie has been set), however only on the page that the cookie is being set. I'm trying to open a new browser window and use that cookie value, however, it won't read the cookie.

I'm also on localhost on my local machine, so I believe that's where the error lies.

How can I fix it so that the cookie I set can be used across all pages on localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works for me

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

setCookie('test', 'Bond007', 365);

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. Is this on a localhost server?